# Do background-color property not works on display "inline"?

Tags: html, inline, background-color

I was just experimenting with code when I applied background color to the inline element (after make div inline) it did not work. I know that height, width, padding, and margin (top and bottom) not works but bg-color should work.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            #box-1{
                display: inline;
                border:2px solid rebeccapurple;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box-1">
            <h2>heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores doloremque nulla earum repudiandae aliquam iure hic culpa recusandae autem quam voluptate blanditiis atque alias, quaerat cum, officia enim. Voluptate, non!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box-2">
            <h2>heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores doloremque nulla earum repudiandae aliquam iure hic culpa recusandae autem quam voluptate blanditiis atque alias, quaerat cum, officia enim. Voluptate, non!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box-3">
            <h2>heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores doloremque nulla earum repudiandae aliquam iure hic culpa recusandae autem quam voluptate blanditiis atque alias, quaerat cum, officia enim. Voluptate, non!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The children of `#box-1` either need to also be `display: inline`, or `display: inline-block`, for them to affect the parent inline element width/height. It's not common for inline elements to have children.

Comment: "It's not common for inline elements to have children." hum.. `<ruby>`, `<picture>`, `<select>` `<datalist>` almost always have children Elements, and its really not uncommon to see in `<a>`, `<code>` or even `<video>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the value display: inherit in a paragraph because these are default values of paragraph display: block

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #box-1{
            display: inline;
            border:2px solid rebeccapurple;
            background-color: red;
        }
        
        p.p-box-1 {
    display: inherit;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box-1">
        <h2>heading</h2>
        <p class="p-box-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores doloremque nulla earum repudiandae aliquam iure hic culpa recusandae autem quam voluptate blanditiis atque alias, quaerat cum, officia enim. Voluptate, non!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-2">
        <h2>heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores doloremque nulla earum repudiandae aliquam iure hic culpa recusandae autem quam voluptate blanditiis atque alias, quaerat cum, officia enim. Voluptate, non!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-3">
        <h2>heading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores doloremque nulla earum repudiandae aliquam iure hic culpa recusandae autem quam voluptate blanditiis atque alias, quaerat cum, officia enim. Voluptate, non!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```